# IdentityServer 3 returns invalid_client

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 with EF. I have API project and i want to authenticate its access using `access token`.
So based on [sample](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html) i have configured client ( for API project) in identity server as below

**Client Properties**

[image]

**Client Secret**
*(Note whatever the text i put as secret value, the admin UI automatically convert it)*

[image]

**Scope**
[image]

Then using POSTMAN i am trying get access token, but i always get `invalid_client` error
[image]

I have also tried getting access token using C# code, but get the same error

```
    static TokenResponse GetClientToken()
    {
        var client = new TokenClient(
            "https://xxxxxxxx/connect/token",
            "A0AD7FB8-2881-484F-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "a84iThYxAA5eZpkIzt9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        return client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api").Result;
    }
```

**Update 1**
Here is what i see in identity server's log

2018-12-21 19:29:59.284 +00:00 [Information] Start token request
2018-12-21 19:29:59.301 +00:00 [Debug] Start client validation
2018-12-21 19:29:59.302 +00:00 [Debug] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2018-12-21 19:29:59.302 +00:00 [Debug] Start parsing for secret in post body
2018-12-21 19:29:59.304 +00:00 [Debug] Parser found secret: "PostBodySecretParser"
2018-12-21 19:29:59.304 +00:00 [Information] Secret id found: "A0AD7FB8-2881-484F-ABE0-xxxxxxxx"
2018-12-21 19:29:59.943 +00:00 [Debug] Skipping secret: no description, secret is not of type SharedSecret.
2018-12-21 19:29:59.943 +00:00 [Debug] No matching hashed secret found.
2018-12-21 19:29:59.943 +00:00 [Information] Secret validators could not validate secret
2018-12-21 19:29:59.944 +00:00 [Information] Client validation failed.
2018-12-21 19:29:59.945 +00:00 [Information] End token request
2018-12-21 19:29:59.946 +00:00 [Information] Returning error: invalid_client

**Update 2**
(The the secret value is updated than what i have posted earlier)
[image]

Comment: Secret id found: "A0AD7FB8-2881-484F-ABE0-xxxxxxxx". Is this Guid intended to be client id, not secret?

Comment: yes its intended to be clientid, you can see that in the client properties. The screen shot i have attached

Comment: I mean if there is same log error for both C# and Postman, you need double check where you save and retrieve your ClientId, because I guess you have it swapped with secret id.

Comment: i verified they are correct. I am thinking it has to do with the type of the client's secret? what should be the `type` of client secret? any string?

Comment: maybe use "client_credentials" instead of "clientsecret" ? maybe this field on UI refers to grant type?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to help you if you don't share more code.

Comment: well there is not much code involved. Its all IdSvr settings which i have already posted

Comment: Try secret type as `SharedSecret` instead of `clientsecret`

Answer (score 2):

Try secret type as `SharedSecret` instead of `clientsecret`. Identity Server 3 has the below secret types:

- SharedSecret
- X509Thumbprint
- X509Name
- X509CertificateBase64

[Taken from Identity Server 3 source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/e6024ddbb7a6e6bf23e9fbcdffef6da9833c54c1/source/Core/Constants.cs#L647)

Also, additionally you seem to be using hash value of the secret when sending auth requests `a84iThYxAA5eZpkIzt9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, however, you need to use the plain text value that you used to create the secret. (`58b9....`)

Comment: @LP13 Can you take a look at the database for IdentityServer3 and check the table ClientSecrets (or something like that), what is the secret type being stored there? Your logs are saying it's not `SharedSecret` type. Also in your c# version you are using `a84iThYxAA5eZpkIzt9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` as secret value, however, that is the hash of the secret and you should instead use the plain text value that you set up during adding secret.

Comment: @LP13 Ok, that looks good. Now just update the client secret being sent in the request to actual value you used when you created it before it got hashed.

Comment: you are correct, i have to use the secret value that i entered in plain text and also type should be `SharedSecret`. That solves `invalid_client` error.. But now i get `invalid_scope` error. Log says `Client cannot request OpenID scopes in client credentials flow'

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `client_credentials` flow cannot make use of OpenID scopes, such as `openid email profile` so remove those. These scopes are intended for when there is user present in `implicit flow` or `authorization code` flow (there are others as well)

Comment: @LP13 also, feel free to join the chat room. I can help you there. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185631/identity-server-3-invalid-scope

Comment: @LP13 no problems, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could encounter invalid_client error in the different, quite curious case.

Updating IdentityServer3.EntityFramework (IS3.EF) to 2.5.1 seems to cause a change in both client secret and scope secret's default behaviour. Below this version even if you don't provide value for secret type in a database (leaving it as null) Identity Server will treat it as "SharedSecret". It sets it as such in class's constructor at the application level.

However, the newer IS.EF3 package contains an update of AutoMapper to 5.0 version. This update as a side effect seems to stop executing default constructors (with given configuration). This way setting client secret type in the database becomes de facto mandatory. Otherwise, you get invalid_client error, because secrets don't match their type.

It looks like authors intended to fix this behaviour change, but the branch hasn't been merged into master up till now:

[ID3.EF - idea_for_setting_defaults_on_entities](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/tree/idea_for_setting_defaults_on_entities)

Be advised, there already is Identity Server  4, so the merge may never occur.