# IdentityServer 3 returns invalid_client when trying to authenticate with Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have an old IdentityServer 3 implementation and I'm trying not to change it to a newer version, I have been trying to authenticate a Blazor wasm application with it and so far almost everything went fine

***Blazor Program.cs***

```cs
...
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
});
```

***Blazor appsettings.json***

```json
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:44343/",
    "ClientId": "clientid",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7170/authentication/login-callback",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7170/authentication/logout-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

just for testing purposes I added a new in memory client in my identityserver

***IdentityServer 3 Clients***

```cs
new Client {
  ClientName = "client",
    ClientId = "clientid",
    Enabled = true,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
    Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCodeWithProofKey,
    RequireConsent = false,
    ClientSecrets = new List < Secret > {
      new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = {
      "https://localhost:7170/authentication/login-callback",
      "https://localhost:7170/connect/authorize/callback"
    },

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {
      "https://localhost:7170/authentication/logout-callback"
    },
    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
    AllowedScopes = new List < string > {
      Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
      Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
      Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
      Constants.StandardScopes.Roles,
      "Api"
    }
}
```

I tried both with

> Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCodeWithProofKey

and

> Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCode

the problem is that when I try and login everything works fine until a /connect/token request is issued to which the server responds with **invalid_client**

I might have a clue on why this is happening but so far nothing I tried has done anything

as far as I know IdentityServer 3 requires the client secret and I didn't find a way around this so I tried to set it on the appsettings with:

> "ClientSecret" : "secret"

but nothing changes

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the logs on your server to have extended information about what happens. Taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889458/identityserver-3-returns-invalid-client) might help also. Finally, are you sure about the hash you are doing on your secret when creating you client? Does IdentityServer3 do the same hash on your ClientSecret when you are trying to login? Are you sure it is not automatically hashed again when creating your Client which would make "secret".Sha256() the real secret (By the way, sha256 is not considered safe anymore).

Comment: the logs just say, no ClientSecret provided, thats because blazor dont send the ClientSecret by default and i dont really want to include that in the client even with PKCE

Comment: What `Blazor` is it? It is UI `Blazor WabAssembly` app, or UI `Blazor Server` app? Or you are trying to auth on your API side (so this is sort of `ASP.NET Core` API `Program.cs` and `appSettings.json`)?  Please put more light on the context you are trying to succeed in.

Comment: Blazor WASM, as stated in the question, I'm trying to authenticate with the authorization code flow (OIDC)

Comment: i was able to connect using request_type id_token token but access_code would be a better flow

Comment: hi @IvanAmbla, Would you like to share your solution, may be in Github or just code snippet, for example, program.cs content?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer3 requires a client secret even though it's optional for authorization code flow with PKCE extension. You can implement a custom ISecretParser to produce a placeholder client secret when none is present.

**IdentityServer3 SecretlessPostBodySecretParser.cs**

```
public class SecretlessPostBodySecretParser : ISecretParser
{
    private readonly IdentityServerOptions options;

    public SecretlessPostBodySecretParser(IdentityServerOptions options)
        => this.options = options;

    public async Task<ParsedSecret> ParseAsync(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(environment);
        // Get ReadRequestFormAsync implementation from:
        // https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/2.6.3/source/Core/Extensions/InternalOwinExtensions.cs
        var body = await context.ReadRequestFormAsync();
        if (body == null) return null;

        var id = body.Get("client_id");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) return null;
        if (id.Length > options.InputLengthRestrictions.ClientId) return null;

        var secret = body.Get("client_secret");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secret)) return null;

        return new ParsedSecret
        {
            Id = id,
            Credential = "not-specified",
            Type = Constants.ParsedSecretTypes.SharedSecret
        };
    }
}
```

**IdentityServer3 Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var serviceFactory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
        serviceFactory.SecretParsers.Add(new Registration<ISecretParser, SecretlessPostBodySecretParser>());
        ...

        app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            Factory = serviceFactory,
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

**IdentityServer3 Client**

```
new Client
{
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("not-specified".Sha256())
    },
    ...
}
```